# RMarkdown: How to end tabbed content

Tags: r, r-markdown

Once I have defined tabs, how do I define content outside/below tabs? Or, how do I end tabbed content?

I have planned a layout like so:

```
title
content above tabbed region.

tab1 tab2
-------------------
tab content 1
-------------------
content below tabbed region
```

which in rmarkdown would be

```
## title {.tabset .tabset-fade}
content above tabbed region.

### tab 1 
tab content 1
### tab 2
tab content 2

content below tabbed region.
```

But, `content below tabbed region.` appears as part of tab2. How can it be defined outside of the tab?

Perhaps I might have further headings in content below. So a related question would be how can I define which headings to be part of tab and which ones not to be?

Comment: Also RTFM'ed and didn't find any information about defining tabset boundaries. Manual page: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html

Answer (score 82, accepted):

My approach to this problem is simple, but it works:

```
## title {.tabset .tabset-fade}
content above tabbed region.

### tab 1 

tab content 1

### tab 2

tab content 2

##

content below tabbed region
```

The tab works only for 'sub-headers of the header with the.tabset
attribute to appear within tabs rather than as standalone section' (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/rmarkdown.pdf))

So you just have to define a new header (in this case no title) one level above the tabs to signalize RMD not to be in a tabbed section.

[image]

It is also possible to design a document with different tabs in different headers:

```
## section 1 {.tabset .tabset-fade}
content above tabbed region.

### tab 1 

tab content 1

### tab 2

tab content 2

## section 2 {.tabset .tabset-fade}

### tab 1 

tab content 1

### tab 2

tab content 2

### tab 3

tab content 3

#
content below tabbed region
```

[image]

**Edit**: If you want to **use a Table of Content (TOC)** there is a problem with the solution above, because the last `#` will create an empty entry in the TOC. The solution here is to use

```
## {.unlisted .unnumbered}

content below tabbed region
```

Comment: Can this syntax be embedded under section titles / subtitles (e.g. a tabset at section 2 and another one at section 3) ? (p.s. I am new to R markdown but need an immediate solution at work.)

Comment: yes, this works, see [here](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4405/68otcmt6_jpg.htm)

Comment: When automatic section numbering is in use, then `##` creates a level 2 heading with numbers. It can be hidden from the TOC using `## {.toc-ignore}`, but it is still visible in the document. @conrad-mac's solution using `</div>` worked better for this particular situation.

Answer (score 15):

Use `{-}` for removing the TOC numbers, after ending the tabbed content

```
tab content 2
## section 2 {.tabset .tabset-fade}
### tab 1 
tab content 1
### tab 2
tab content 2
### tab 3
tab content 3
## {-}
content below tabbed region
```

Answer (score 13):

An alternative is to use a closing div tag (i.e.`</div>`). See the following:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Title {.tabset .tabset-fade}
Content above tabbed region.

### Tab 1 
Tab 1 content

### Tab 2
Tab 2 content

</div>

Content below tabbed region
````

Comment: This works good if table of content (toc: false) is deactivated. Otherwise the content after `</div>` will not be included

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include content related to a parent tab and leave a children tabset, for example

```
[Parent tab 1] __Parent tab 2__
[Child tab 1] __Child tab 2__
<Child tab 1 content>
---
<Parent tab 1 other content>
```

where `<Parent tab 1 other content>` is shown regardless of selected `[Child tab]`, try this Rmd, which is a little bit hacked by JavaScript:

````
---
title: "Nested tabs example"
---

```{js}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  $(".leave-tabset").removeClass("tab-pane tabbed-pane");
}, false);
```

# Nested tabs example {.tabset}

## Parent 1 {.tabset}

### Parent 1, Child 1

Parent 1, Child 1 content

### Parent 1, Child 2

Parent 1, Child 2 content

### {- .leave-tabset}

---

#### Parent 1, Other content 1

Foo 1

#### Parent 1, Other content 2

Bar 1

<!-- next main tab -->

## Parent 2 {.tabset}

### Parent 2, Child 1

Parent 2, Child 1 content

### Parent 2, Child 2

Parent 2, Child 2 content

### {- .leave-tabset}

---

#### Parent 2, Other content 1

Foo 2

#### Parent 2, Other content 2

Bar 2

<!-- next main tab -->

## Parent 3 {.tabset}

### Parent 3, Child 1

Parent 3, Child 1 content

### Parent 3, Child 2

Parent 3, Child 2 content

### {- .leave-tabset}

---

#### Parent 3, Other tabs {.tabset}

##### Parent 3, Other tab 1

Foo 3

##### Parent 3, Other tab 2

Bar 3
````

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

As you can see in `Parent 3` tab, you can even define new tabsets after you leave the parent's child ones. But you will probably be short of header levels soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Check manual [rmarkdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-tabs.html):

```
## Results {.tabset}

### Tab One

### Tab Two

## {-}
```

> With the above unnumbered (`{-}`) and empty section header, we can end
> the tabset and continue to write more paragraphs.