# r Markdown (html_document): plot in tabbed headings

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a simple r markdown document:

```
---
title: "An interactive application (Knitr + Shiny)"
author: ""
date: "Wednesday, September 27, 2016"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```

And I also have a lot of plotly charts there, such as:

```
library(plotly)
m <- list(
l = 50,
r = 50,
b = 100,
t = 100,
pad = 4
)
plot_ly(x = seq(0, 8), y = seq(0, 8)) %>%
  layout(autosize = F, width = 500, height = 500, margin = m)
```

I'd like to have each chart in separate tabbed headings - something like html bookmarks. How can I do that in r markdown document. Thanks a lot for any of your advice.

Can I do something like

```
## title {.tabset .tabset-fade}
content above tabbed region.

### tab 1 

plot_ly(x = seq(0, 8), y = seq(0, 8)) %>%
  layout(autosize = F, width = 500, height = 500, margin = m)

### tab 2

plot_ly(x = seq(0, 8), y = seq(0, 8)) %>%
  layout(autosize = F, width = 500, height = 500, margin = m)
```

How can I have each of plotly charts in separate tabbed headings?

Comment: not completely sure what you mean by bookmark. Do you just mean being able to use `http://example.com/report.html#plot1` or did you mean having it in a separate tab in a document panel?

Comment: You mean this here? Different tabs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062706/rmarkdown-tabbed-and-untabbed-headings/38146093#38146093

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks a lot for the link !!!!