# Rmarkdown: Placing static content under a tabbed section

Tags: html, r, tabs, knitr, r-markdown

I was hoping for help placing static content under a tabbed section in my R markdown file.  It's similar to this question: [RMarkdown: Tabbed and Untabbed headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062706/rmarkdown-tabbed-and-untabbed-headings), but the solution doesn't account for blank lines in the table of contents.

Is it possible to end the tabbed section without starting a new section?  Here's an example:

````
---
title: "Mtcars Example"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: true
---

# Mtcars Info
The data was extracted from the 1974 Motor Trend US magazine..

# Dataset Prep
No changes were made to the dataset..

# Plots {.tabset .tabset-pills}
```{r results = 'hide', message = FALSE, fig.height = 5, fig.width = 5, echo = FALSE}
    plot1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars) + 
            geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = hp))
    plot2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars) + 
            geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = wt))
```  

## mpg vs hp  
```{r, echo = FALSE}
plot1
```  

## mpg vs wt  
```{r, echo = FALSE}
plot2
```  

#
The plots above show how mpg is related.. 

# Analysis
the mtcars dataset is a great exploratory dataset to show..
````

Section 3 is a tabbed section allowing the user to switch between plots.  I'd like to have static text underneath it.

The problem is, without starting a new heading, the content is only visible when the 2nd tab is selected.  Not good.  I can fix this by starting a new heading and putting the content in there.. but now I have a numbered section 4 in my table of contents that's blank.  Also not desirable.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?  In the Rmarkdown cheatsheet https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf, you supposedly can end a tabbed section with ###, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am not sure about any built-in solution. In such cases I usually just go with jQuery. In this case, it is a one-liner.*

### Reproducible Example:

````
---
title: "Mtcars Example"
output: 
  html_document:
    number_sections: true
---

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDiv').appendTo('#first-tab-sec');
});
</script>

<div id="myDiv">a
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>

# Plots {.tabset .tabset-pills #first-tab-sec}

## mpg vs hp  
```{r, echo = FALSE}
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp)
```  

## mpg vs wt  
```{r, echo = FALSE}
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$wt)
```  

# Next Section
````

We created a div element with the id `myDiv`. Inside that element we store the content, thats supposed to go underneath the tabbed area.

**The jQuery (JS) snippet does the following:**

As soon as the document finished loading (`$(document).ready()`), we execute the anonymous `function(){...}`. Inside that function we grab our div element by its id and append it to the element with the id `first-tab-sec`.

### Multiple Tabbed Sections

If we have another tabbed-section, we just give it a new id, for example `second-tab-sec`, and add the code

```
$('#mySecDiv').appendTo('#second-tab-sec');
```

to the JS chunk. Here we assume that the content is contained within a div with the id `mySecDiv`.

Comment: This looks great!  I tried it out and it does what I want.  Quick question though.. what happens if you have a second tabbed section with different content?  I tried adding another jQuery snippet, but it copies the text under every tabbed section.

Comment: Edited my answer. We can identify our tabbed section by giving it a unique id.

Comment: Finally had a chance to try it out.  Works perfectly!