# RMarkdown can't seem to produce Tabs in Tabs

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am trying to make a static webpage using RMarkdown. I want to define a UI which has a first layer of tabs and then tabs underneath the first layer. I've already looked into a similar question at [RMarkdown: Tabbed and Untabbed headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062706/rmarkdown-tabbed-and-untabbed-headings) . But that answer doesn't help my cause. Please find below the tab structure that I want to acheive.

```
| Results
* Discussion of Results

           | Quarterly Results
           * This content pertains to Quarterly Results

                      | By Product
                      * Quarterly Performance by Products

                      | By Region
                      * Quarterly Performance by Region

* Final Words about Quarterly Results

           | Yearly Results
           * This content pertains to Yearly Results

                      | By Product
                      * Yearly Performance by Products

                      | By Region
                      * Yearly Performance by Region

* Final Words about Yearly Results
```

Here is the script in .Rmd format that I was using. But the output I was able to achieve look likes this [Current Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgtDz.png). I'd want to have `Final Words about Quarterly Results` and `Final Words about Yearly Results` outside the Region tab and in Quarterly Results and Yearly Results respectively.

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    theme: paper
    highlight: tango
    number_sections: false
    toc: false
    toc_float: false
---
# Result Discussion {.tabset}
We will discuss results here

## Quarterly Results {.tabset}
This content pertains to Quarterly Results

### By Product

Quarterly perfomance by Products

### By Region

Quarterly perfomance by Region


Final Words about Quarterly Results

## Yearly Results {.tabset}
This content pertains to Yearly Results

### By Product

Yearly perfomance by Products

### By Region

Yearly perfomance by Region

Final Words about Yearly Results
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the last paragraphs (`Final Words about Quarterly Results` and `Final Words about Yearly Results`) belong to the last level 3 section and not to the parent level 2 section.
You have to manually control the sectioning of the rendered `HTML` to obtain what you want.

Using **`pandoc` < 2.0**, the only mean is to insert raw `HTML`:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    theme: paper
    highlight: tango
    number_sections: false
    toc: false
    toc_float: false
---
# Result Discussion {.tabset}
We will discuss results here

## Quarterly Results {.tabset}
This content pertains to Quarterly Results

<div id="quarterly-product" class="section level3">
### By Product

Quarterly perfomance by Products
</div>

<div id="quarterly-region" class="section level3">
### By Region

Quarterly perfomance by Region
</div>

Final Words about Quarterly Results


## Yearly Results {.tabset}
This content pertains to Yearly Results

<div id="yearly-product" class="section level3">
### By Product

Yearly perfomance by Products
</div>

<div id="yearly-region" class="section level3">
### By Region

Yearly perfomance by Region
</div>

Final Words about Yearly Results
```

If you use **`pandoc` 2.0 or greater**, you can use [fenced `divs`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fenced_divs):

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    theme: paper
    highlight: tango
    number_sections: false
    toc: false
    toc_float: false
---
# Result Discussion {.tabset}
We will discuss results here

## Quarterly Results {.tabset}
This content pertains to Quarterly Results

::: {#quarterly-product .section .level3}
### By Product

Quarterly perfomance by Products
:::

::: {#quarterly-region .section .level3}
### By Region

Quarterly perfomance by Region
:::

Final Words about Quarterly Results


## Yearly Results {.tabset}
This content pertains to Yearly Results

::: {#yearly-product .section .level3}
### By Product

Yearly perfomance by Products
:::

::: {#yearly-region .section .level3}
### By Region

Yearly perfomance by Region
:::

Final Words about Yearly Results
```

Comment: Both the `HTML` and `Pandoc` solutions work. While applying your solution, I've come across a scenario where I need multiple `level 3` tabs under a single tab. 

Like this https://imgur.com/R6jKyPM. I've replicated your solution twice to get the desired result, but all my tabs ended up together like this https://imgur.com/J3WjrKX. Do you have any idea where I could've gone wrong?

Attaching the link to the code

[https://gist.github.com/Ravi1008/51b01909f945b6b52ad5d57515b1d0c8#file-current-rmd]

Comment: @RaviKrishna be careful, `HTML` elements `id`s must be unique. Correct this first, please.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Thanks for pointing out. Updated the Code on gist.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this ? :

```
output:
  html_document:
    theme: paper
    highlight: tango
    number_sections: false
    toc: false
    toc_float: false
---
# Result Discussion {.tabset}
We will discuss results here

## Quarterly Results {.tabset}
This content pertains to Quarterly Results

### By Product

Quarterly perfomance by Products

### By Region

Quarterly perfomance by Region


##
Final Words about Quarterly Results

## Yearly Results {.tabset}
This content pertains to Yearly Results

### By Product

Yearly perfomance by Products

### By Region

Yearly perfomance by Region

##
Final Words about Yearly Results
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've actually tried out this solution before posting on SO. But adding the "#" didn't solve the problem. I am ending up with separate un-named tabs with `Final Words about Quarterly Results` & `Final Words about Yearly Results`.

Comment: Just so i'm clear: This is what you wanted : https://imgur.com/a/gIQQy
But pasting my code did not produce this result ?

Comment: I want `Quarterly Results` and `Yearly Results` also to be tabsets appearing under Result Discussion, just like say how By Region & By Product appear. 

If I exactly reproduce your code using "##", I end up with this:
https://imgur.com/a/J13AV

If I replace "##" with "#", I get:
https://imgur.com/a/iYpDB

Neither is the exact solution that I'm looking for.

Comment: Yeah, using the #  just creates new headers. My understanding right now is that the flow is linear, so you can can't "link" back to a tab above the tab (without it having to be specific to the lower tab which would create redundancy in your code).