# How to create doubly-nested tabs in R Markdown?

Tags: tabs, r-markdown

I would like to create an R Markdown HTML document with doubly-nested tabs.

I have tried to extend the method given as an answer for the question [RMarkdown can't seem to produce Tabs in Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276336/rmarkdown-cant-seem-to-produce-tabs-in-tabs) with the following code:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    theme: paper
    highlight: tango
    number_sections: false
    toc: false
    toc_float: false
---
# Result Discussion {.tabset}
We will discuss results here

## Quarterly Results {.tabset}
This content pertains to Quarterly Results


<div id="quarterly-product" class="section level3">
### By Product

Quarterly perfomance by Products

<div id="quarterly-product-a" class="section level4">
#### Case A

Quarterly perfomance by Products in Case A
</div>

<div id="quarterly-product-b" class="section level4">
#### Case B

Quarterly perfomance by Products in Case B
</div>

End of section quarterly perfomance by Products
</div>


<div id="quarterly-region" class="section level3">
### By Region

Quarterly perfomance by Region

<div id="quarterly-region-a" class="section level4">
#### Case A

Quarterly perfomance by Region in Case A
</div>

<div id="quarterly-region-b" class="section level4">
#### Case B

Quarterly perfomance by Region in Case B
</div>

End of section quarterly perfomance by Region
</div>

Final Words about Quarterly Results


## Yearly Results {.tabset}
This content pertains to Yearly Results

<div id="yearly-product" class="section level3">
### By Product

Yearly perfomance by Products
</div>

<div id="yearly-region" class="section level3">
### By Region

Yearly perfomance by Region
</div>

Final Words about Yearly Results
```

Here, I added subsections Case A and Case B in the sections Quarterly results by Product and Quarterly results by Region. However, adding level4 sections using the < div> tags doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to have a third layer of tabs in this way?