# Empty headings in table of contents when RMarkdown contains tabs?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When making an RMarkdown [containing tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38146093/5783745), some extra (blank) items appear in the table of contents.

#### Example

This generates the html doc below

````
---
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# First Tabs {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

Text before tabs

## First tab

Content in first tab

## Second tab

Content in second tab

#


# here is another section
Some further content.
````

[image]

Everything is as expected, except there's a blank line in the TOC.

#### What I've tried

I tried replacing the `#` that ends the tabbed content with `</div>` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51978479/5783745). This causes the TOC to populate correctly, but (strangely) causes the content after the tabs to left-align (no idea why)

For ease of reproducibility, here's the code and a screengrab of the resulting HTML

````
---
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# First Tabs {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

Text before tabs

## First tab

Content in first tab

## Second tab

Content in second tab

</div>


# here is another section
Some further content.
````

[image]

Comment: Just remove the single `#`

Comment: @J_F thanks, I’ll try now. Why do you have it in the linked answer though? (tbh, I don’t quite understand how knitr interprets it, I have followed your answer (including closing #) and found it works perfectly with the toc being the only exception

Comment: @J_F I tested on a large file, with many tabs, and simiply removing the closing hashes works! I am quite confused though, as [not using closing hashes caused problems in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207158/how-to-facet-across-tabs-in-ggplot2-rmarkdown#comment108639268_61208750). I need to read up on the way knitr interprets these structures and converts them to html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the comment: Just remove the single `#`.
There is also a workaorund, if you have have the following problem

- Use TOC
- Use Tabs
- End tabbed region with further text under the tabbed region

Problem: Normaly use `##` to end tabbed region, but this would be another header in the TOC

Solution: `## {.unlisted .unnumbered}` will remove the header from TOC.

Example:

````
---
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## title {.tabset .tabset-fade}
content above tabbed region.

### tab 1 

tab content 1

### tab 2

tab content 2

## {.unlisted .unnumbered}

content below tabbed region
````

[image]

Comment: Great knowledge! A couple of questions: is there any reason not to always use `## .unlisted .unnumbered` to close a tabbed section, as there appears to be no downside? Also, how did you find out about `.unlisted` and `.unnumbered` classes? Are they defined somewhere in kntir css, or pandoc css?

Comment: `.unnumbered` is in the Pandoc manual; `.unlisted` is a relatively new feature, and does not seem to be documented yet. We have mentioned them in these sections in this book: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/unnumbered-sections.html and https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/toc-unlisted.html