# How to name the RMarkdown tab based on the facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Based on this question [How to facet across tabs in ggplot2 / Rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207158/how-to-facet-across-tabs-in-ggplot2-rmarkdown), I am trying to name each tab after its corresponding facet, in this case '~ cut:clarity'. How can this be done? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The automagic_tabs function from sknifedatar package solved this. More info here: [https://distillery.rbind.io/posts/2021-03-24-automagic-tabs-in-distillrmarkdown-files-and-time-series-analysis/#:~:text=%20Automagic%20Tabs%20in%20Distill%2FRmarkdown%20files%20and%20time,on%20each%20sector%2C%20it%20can%20be...%20More%20](https://distillery.rbind.io/posts/2021-03-24-automagic-tabs-in-distillrmarkdown-files-and-time-series-analysis/#:%7E:text=%20Automagic%20Tabs%20in%20Distill%2FRmarkdown%20files%20and%20time,on%20each%20sector%2C%20it%20can%20be...%20More%20)