# Create a carousel in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, slickr

Is there any quick and easy way to create a simple [carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) in an Rmarkdown doc?

#### What I know so far

I found [slickr](https://cran.csiro.au/web/packages/texPreview/vignettes/slickr.html) but run into errors setting options and knitting (the errors could be specific to me / mac - I am not sure at this point).

I believe it would be possible to hard code html/javascript into the RMarkdown doc i.e. the same way a carousel would be done in any other (regular) html document (i.e. using the html code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp))- but I wonder if there's a native (R) way?

#### Example use

In my particular use case, I'm trying to display multiple complicated ggplots which are each sufficiently complex to make them require their own space (i.e. not faceted or `grid.arrange` as the size of each plot will get too small to read

#### Notes

Here is the slickr code I tried

```
library(texPreview)
library(slickR)


objpath <- file.path(getwd(),"slickr_files/figure-html")

if(!dir.exists(objpath)) { dir.create(objpath,recursive = TRUE) }

tex_opts$set(
  fileDir    = objpath, # path to save output
  returnType = 'html', # return images ready for html 
  imgFormat  = 'png' # return png images
)


knitr::kable(mtcars,'latex') %>%
  texPreview::tex_preview(stem = 'kable-1')
# ! LaTeX Error: File `standalone.cls' not found.
```

A side note, if there's a better way of providing many (e.g. > 3) large, detailed plots that doesn't involve faceting, grid.arrange, or (my current preferred option) [tabbing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38146093/5783745), please give a suggestion as a comment

Answer (score 4):

The [example](https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/texPreview/blob/master/vignettes/slickr.Rmd) works fine for me. Be sure to save your plots in the folder `slickr_files/figure-html`.

Then run:

````
```{r}
slickR::slickR(
    list.files(objpath,full.names = TRUE,pattern = 'png'),
    height = 200,
    width = '95%')
```
````

Comment: link is broken and should be https://yonicd.github.io/slickR/articles/basics.html